# Jquery Radio Button uncheck radio button, but should not clear value part

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, reset

I am trying to clear my form fields on reset button using following code

```
$(':input',formId).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('selected');
```

Now my Radio button is getting unchecked, but value set in radio button is also getting cleared.

I want only to uncheck it, But value of the radio button should be available.

Comment: A test case on jsfiddle can help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) function here:

```
formId.reset();
```

`reset` resets the form to its initial state.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9c3F/)

Comment: But I don't want hidden fields data to be lost

Comment: Hidden fields data is not lost by `reset`, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9c3F/1/)

Comment: @Palash - Now trying your solution. Thanx

Comment: @Palash - I tried `$(#myForm).reset();` and I got java script error reset is not defined.

Comment: I have tried the fiddle demo link, It worked there but I am getting Error: TypeError: $(...)[0].reset is not a function

Comment: Please show me the code you have written. Is it `$('#myForm')[0].reset();` or else. If possible, post your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Yes I have written `$('#myForm')[0].reset();` where myForm is my form Id. Please give me some time I will give the complete code also

Comment: @Palash - I am providing the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw5LK/2/) link of my code. Its is with css.

Comment: Ok, the issue seems to occur since the `Reset` button is inside the form. If we put it outside the form like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pw5LK/3/) it works fine!

Answer (score 4):

don't clear the value, i.e. remove `.val('')`. This is setting your value to blank. so you want to do this

```
$(':input[type!=checkbox]',formId).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('')
        .removeAttr('selected');
```

then this

```
$(':input[type=checkbox]',formId).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
        .removeAttr('checked');
```

you don't need `.removeAttr('selected')`. Chekboxes only have a checked attribute, see [w3c here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html)

more info on the selectors used [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Whats difference between selected and checked?

Comment: Thanx @Lima using your input my app is working perfectly. below I am mentioned how have it work.
<code>
$(':input',formId).not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
$(':input[type=text]',formId).val(''); 
var divId = '#' + divIds;
$(divId).empty();
var comboBoxId = '#' + comboBoxIds;
$(comboBoxId).find('option:not(:first)').remove();
</code>