# Reset allinput boxes of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
<div class="attack_options">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
              <input type="text" name="date" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>
              <input type="text" name="date2" /></td>
        </tr>
.
.
.

  </table>
</div>
```

I want to clear all the input fields data on a event.

I tried:

```
$('table').trigger("reset");
```

OK above is wrong I think But what is the problem with

```
$('.attack_options').find('input:text').val('');
```

Please help what might I am doing wrong here

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17234386/1823841

Comment: You serious? There is no such thing as a reset event on a table. You probably want a form here.

Comment: You are right there is no any such event But I  tried this   $('.heart_attack_options').find('input:text').val('');
  But doesn't work

Comment: @PalashMondal  that is for form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in one line using:

```
function reset() {
   $(".attack_options input").val('');
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/CCFCC/

To target inputs of type text add the attribute selector:

```
function reset() {
   $(".attack_options input[type=text]").val('');
}
```

Comment: Thanks man I was doing a mistake now I define class for my table also this answer helps me

Answer (score 0):

```
function reset() {
   $(".attack_options input").val('');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yBQB3/1/

Comment: Why `each()`?  You can do it without

Comment: @Archer - went for speed. Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: @DarrenDavies   is there any single line answer for this

Comment: @burning if you had the elements in a form you could just have input with type=reset